# sympy.simplify doesn't work on "tanh^2(x-y) + sech^2(x-y)"

Tags: python, sympy

I use `sympy (ver1.9)`.

I calculate the following expressions((1)~(4)) by `sympy.simplify()`.
All of them are expected to be identical to 1 analytically.

but (4) did not return 1, and the expression isn't simplified.

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/BY7qg.png]

Why does this happen?

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! From my experience on this site It would be better to type the `sympy` input in your post than to embed the image.

Comment: @DmitriChubarov, actually this is one of the more readable images, especially since it doesn't require opening a separate image.  And it's nicely color highlighted.   But yes, a copy-n-paste of the interactive session would be nice, since that allows us to in turn copy-n-paste parts of the code to our own interactive session.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try rewriting to `exp` and then simplifying:

```
>>> eq=tanh(x-y)**2 + sech(x-y)**2
>>> eq.rewrite(exp).simplify()
1
```

or use the function to rewrite hyperbolics to trigonometric functions before simplifying, e.g. with fu:

```
>>> from sympy.simplify.fu import hyper_as_trig
>>> e,f=hyper_as_trig(eq)
>>> f(fu(e))
1
```

See also `hyper_as_trig` in simplify/fu.py.